# Show log4j logs in the Eclipse RCP Console View

Tags: eclipse, logging, eclipse-plugin, log4j, rcp

I added log4j to my Eclipse RCP application. Appending logs to a file works fine. Appending to the console works, but only if I run my application from command line or when I debug it (then, logs are shown in the Console View of the host Eclipse)

I want logs to be shown in the console view in RCP. I set that view in my perspective extention, and tried to pass the `-Dforce-ide-log-level=debug` argument, but it doesn't work. Should I give special arguments in my `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: I think you need a custom log4j log appender to show log entries in the console view. The log appender would need to create its own `IConsole` page to list log entries. Depending on how 'chatty' you log4j log is, an alternative approach may be to use the `StatusManager` in a custom log appender to feed entries to the workbench log that can be viewed with the _Error Log_ view.

Comment: Hey @Morpheus. Did you have any luck with that? I'm trying to do the same thing.